# Avoid expired dates in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following airflow DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

#Runs every 1 minute
dag = DAG(dag_id='example_dag', start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1), schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *')

t1 = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task', bash_command='echo Hello!', dag=dag)
```

Problem here is that Airflow is scheduling and executing tasks from past dates like the first minute of 2020, the second minute of 2020, the third minute of 2020 and so on.

I want Airflow to schedule and execute only the tasks that occur after the dag deploy (i.e. if I deploy today, I want the first task to be executed in the next minute) and not to execute expired tasks.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, "expired" tasks are tasks which are before the current time of deployment? Have you tried setting `catchup=False`?

Comment: Yes, that was the aswer. I posted it yesterday and a moderator deleted it because I quoted a medium article (don't ask me why)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-tips-and-best-practices-ff64ce92ef8). Read the "Catchup and Idempotent DAG" section.